# How to store a Telnet output into a variable in python

Tags: python, telnet

I am trying to use telnet to run a command and grab a value from a text output and store it in a variable in python. In the image, the value I am trying to grab is the External alarm contact 2: Analog input value. In this case 5.99 which I want stored in a variable.
I need to store the 5.99 value or whatever it may change to in a variable :

[image: I need to store the 5.99 value or whatever it may change to in a variable]

Comment: Python provides the "telnetlib" module to access a telnet server. So you can read the data and find the specific information. If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code.

Comment: telnet lib example: https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html#telnet-example

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [`telnetlib` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html) for Python, you can use `read_until()` and specify a string it should read up to, or `read_all()` to read the output until EOF and obtain the output from the string.

```py
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib

HOST = "localhost"
user = raw_input("Enter your remote account: ")
password = getpass.getpass()

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.read_until("login: ")
tn.write(user + "\n")
if password:
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(password + "\n")

tn.write("ls\n")
tn.write("exit\n")

print tn.read_all()
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html#telnet-objects